# How to sync Thunderbird calendar on laptop with calendar on Samsung Galaxy S III

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I want to sync my Thunderbird Lightning calendar on my office laptop with my Samsung S III calendar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using the Google calendar?

As far as I know you can sync the Samsung S III and the Thunderbird Lightning calendar with the Google calendar.

Samsung SIII:
http://www.samsunggalaxys3forum.com/forum/samsung-galaxy-s3-help/1278-samsung-s3-s-calendar-not-syncing-google-calendar.html

Lightning:
http://www.vikitech.com/7955/sync-google-yahoo-windows-live-calendars-thunderbirds-lightning

Answer (score 0):

As you don't specify, I assume your office laptop is running Windows. In this case you might want to take a look at the [MyPhoneExplorer Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) App for your SGS, and its desktop pendant for your laptop. As far as I know (I'm not a Windows user), this should be the best and complete solution -- not only caring for your calendar with Thunderbird and others, but doing a lot more useful things to manage your device.

If you do not care for those extras, you might rather take a look at [BirdieSync for Thunderbird](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callicia.birdiesync) (or simply [search the playstore for thunderbird](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=thunderbird&c=apps)).